# Mentions in Microsoft bot framework v4

Tags: botframework

Is there a way to mention someone in Microsoft Bot Framework v4? There is a possibility to check if there was somebody mentioned in the answer from the user, but I'm looking for a solution where the bot can mention someone.

Comment: On which channel? If you are asking for Microsoft Teams, this is not possible yet. (feature request: https://github.com/OfficeDev/BotBuilder-MicrosoftTeams/issues/146)

Comment: I would like to implement it for all channels, i thought in the previous version of the bot framework it was supported for all channels. Teams extensions does support it in the newest version https://github.com/OfficeDev/BotBuilder-MicrosoftTeams-dotnet

Answer (score 0):

All channels handle mentions differently. As @Mick mentioned; the scenario you are wanting (@mentioning someone outside the chat/discussion) isn't possible currently.

I'm not 100% aware on your exact needs, but depending on that, perhaps you could come up with something using a custom dialog and Graph API.